# How to set up a trigger for lambda when there's a new file is S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I've never done this and there's so much material it's kinda overwhelming and I feel like i just keep trying different things and none of them work ...
I have a function that reads from S3 and writes to RS.
I'm trying to figure out how to set up a trigger so it only runs when it detects that new files have been uploaded to an S3 bucket.

I'm kinda confused by whether i should be using SNS or SQS or both. But i have added this to my template and it creates both a Topic and a Queue.

```
 AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  Sample SAM Template

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 600
    MemorySize: 128
    Tracing: Active
  Api:
    TracingEnabled: true

Resources:
  RSUploadFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: <...>
      CodeUri: upload_to_rs/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      PackageType: Zip
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      Policies:
        - Statement:
          - Sid: KMSGenerateDataKey
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - kms:GenerateDataKey
            Resource: arn:aws:kms:<...>
        - Statement:
          - Sid: ExecuteStatement
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - redshift-data:ExecuteStatement
            Resource: arn:aws:redshift:<...>
        - Statement:
          - Sid: DescribeStatement
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - redshift-data:DescribeStatement
            Resource: '*'
        
        - KMSDecryptPolicy:
            KeyId: <...>
        
        - KMSEncryptPolicy:
            KeyId: <...>

        - S3CrudPolicy:
            BucketName: <...>
        - AWSSecretsManagerGetSecretValuePolicy:
            SecretArn: arn:aws:secretsmanager:<...>

      Events:
        SNS1:
          Type: SNS
          Properties:
            Topic:
              Ref: SNSTopic
            Statement:
              Condition:
                ArnLike:
                  aws:SourceArn: arn:aws:s3:::<...>


  SNSTopic:
    Type: "AWS::SNS::Topic"
    Properties:
      DisplayName: "My SNS topic"
      Subscription:
        -
          Endpoint:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - "RSUploadFunction"
              - "Arn"
          Protocol: "lambda"
      TopicName: "SNSTopic"

  SQSQueue:
    Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
    Properties:
      VisibilityTimeout: 600
      QueueName: "SQSQueue"

  MyQueuePolicy:
        Type: "AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy"
        Properties:
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service: "sns.amazonaws.com"
              
              Action: "sqs:SendMessage"
              Resource: "*"
              Condition:
                ArnEquals:
                  "aws:SourceArn":
                    !Ref SNSTopic
          Queues: 
            [!Ref SQSQueue]

Outputs:
  Function1:
    Description: "Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt <...>.Arn
```

Now i'm not super sure where to go from here. I tried going into bucket settings and creating an event with either a queue or a topic, but i get the same error:

```
Unknown Error
An unexpected error occurred.
API response
Unable to validate the following destination configurations
```

Really lost as to where to go from here.

Comment: Your template does not include any S3 nor lambda definitions. So exactly where is your trigger defined?

Comment: @Marcin uploaded to include the whole template.yaml.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the below resources,

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html
2. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-s3-notification-lambda/

The essence of the KB article is, you use a custom resource to create a S3 trigger by adding a bucket notification through the `BucketNotification`.`put` API.
One thing you need to be careful about is, in real-world scenarios, there could be other bucket notifications already present. So first call `get_bucket_notification_configuration` and add/update the notifications.

Shamelessly copy-pasting the Cloudformation stack from the aws kb article since a link only answer is not a good idea on SO since they can go dead anytime.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  Sample template to illustrate use of existing S3 bucket as an event source for a Lambda function
Parameters:
  NotificationBucket:
    Type: String
    Default : my-bucket-name
    Description: S3 bucket that's used for the Lambda event notification

Resources:
  S3NotificationLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Join
          - |+

          - - import json
            - 'def lambda_handler(event,context):'
            - '    return ''Welcome... This is a test Lambda Function'''
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaIAMRole.Arn
      Runtime: python3.9
      Timeout: 5

  LambdaInvokePermission:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !GetAtt S3NotificationLambdaFunction.Arn
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceAccount: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
      SourceArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${NotificationBucket}'

  LambdaIAMRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 's3:GetBucketNotification'
                  - 's3:PutBucketNotification'
                Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${NotificationBucket}'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:*:*:*'

  CustomResourceLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaIAMRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: |

            from __future__ import print_function
            import json
            import boto3
            import cfnresponse
            
            SUCCESS = "SUCCESS"
            FAILED = "FAILED"
            
            print('Loading function')
            s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
            
            def lambda_handler(event, context):
                print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
                responseData={}
                try:
                    if event['RequestType'] == 'Delete':
                        print("Request Type:",event['RequestType'])
                        Bucket=event['ResourceProperties']['Bucket']
                        delete_notification(Bucket)
                        print("Sending response to custom resource after Delete")
                    elif event['RequestType'] == 'Create' or event['RequestType'] == 'Update':
                        print("Request Type:",event['RequestType'])
                        LambdaArn=event['ResourceProperties']['LambdaArn']
                        Bucket=event['ResourceProperties']['Bucket']
                        add_notification(LambdaArn, Bucket)
                        responseData={'Bucket':Bucket}
                        print("Sending response to custom resource")
                    responseStatus = 'SUCCESS'
                except Exception as e:
                    print('Failed to process:', e)
                    responseStatus = 'FAILED'
                    responseData = {'Failure': 'Something bad happened.'}
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, responseStatus, responseData)

            def add_notification(LambdaArn, Bucket):
                bucket_notification = s3.BucketNotification(Bucket)
                response = bucket_notification.put(
                  NotificationConfiguration={
                    'LambdaFunctionConfigurations': [
                      {
                          'LambdaFunctionArn': LambdaArn,
                          'Events': [
                              's3:ObjectCreated:*'
                          ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                )
                print("Put request completed....")
              
            def delete_notification(Bucket):
                bucket_notification = s3.BucketNotification(Bucket)
                response = bucket_notification.put(
                    NotificationConfiguration={}
                )
                print("Delete request completed....")
      Runtime: python3.9
      Timeout: 50

  LambdaTrigger:
    Type: 'Custom::LambdaTrigger'
    DependsOn: LambdaInvokePermission
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt CustomResourceLambdaFunction.Arn
      LambdaArn: !GetAtt S3NotificationLambdaFunction.Arn
      Bucket: !Ref NotificationBucket
```

Comment: wow, that is a lot +.+ .... Thanks so much! I guess lemme go and try adding those functions in and see if i can get this thing working. I have also updated my question to include the entire template. It's much smaller. I guess my RSUploadFunction is your CustomResourceLambdaFunction? Except my stuff is on an Image and not a Zip.

Comment: I guess your `RSUploadFunction` is `S3NotificationLambdaFunction`. Wouldn't be able to tell for sure without seeing the `RSUploadFunction` function body.

Comment: You're right, i got that when i got to the code part. RSUploadFunction has all the code in the app.py Do i really need LambdaIAMRole? I haven't needed it before. I think i provide the credentials when i deploy.

Comment: actually that was a lie, this function is a Zip. Doesn't matter tho >.>

Comment: You would need the `LambdaIAMRole`, so that the S3 trigger installer lambda can perform the necessary API calls (`s3:GetBucketNotification`, `s3:PutBucketNotification`), otherwise you will get exception when the lambda trigger happens.

Comment: Oooh, i see, ok. And is the  !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'`  that 12 digit number? So SourceAccount: 123456789123

Comment: yes, but you dont have to worry/replace it, thats a SAM pseudo parameter,  more info here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html

Comment: so i don't need to replace any of the !Ref's? What about !Sub's? I put the actual bucket here: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${NotificationBucket}' ... Or is it supposed to get that from samconfig.toml? Or how does it know

Comment: the only stack parameter here is an existing bucket name, `NotificationBucket`

Comment: that's cool, i didn't know you could define it at the beginning like that. Super handy to not have to rewrite it a bunch.

Comment: hm, i tried setting my bucket parameter like you showed, but it's saying "Property my-bucket is not allowed" Where my-bucket is the actual name of the bucket in S3

Comment: Or is NotificationBucket the name of the parameter and the name of the actual bucket goes elsewhere? >.>

Comment: you are correct, take a look here, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

Comment: I see. But don't you need something like `Default: my-bucket` so that when you call `!Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${NotificationBucket}'` it actually translates to `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket`?

Comment: I'm also getting `Property DependsOn is not allowed` error on `DependsOn: LambdaInvokePermission`

Comment: Also, what's the difference between ServiceToken and LambdaArn? Since i only have one function.

Comment: still getting the same error :(

Comment: won't even deploy now. Saying "CloudFormation did not receive a response from 
                                                                                                                                                   your Custom Resource. Please check your logs "